# how to install tkinter using pip in windows 10

Tags: python, tkinter

When i try to install `tkinter` with the command `pip install tkinter` in windows 10 I get this  error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter(from versions: )
>   No matching distributions found for tkinter

Comment: Tkinter comes installed with a python installation. You can just import it. It's standard library.

Comment: You cannot install tkinter with pip.

Answer (score 5):

`Tkinter` comes bundled with Python. You can use `python -m Tkinter` to check the windows demonstration of `Tk` interface, which lets you know if `Tkinter` is installed properly on your system or not.

In case `Tkinter` is not present on your system, I would recommend reinstalling Python distribution(in case you are using a stale version).

In case your version is also updated and still the problem exists, please install using the binaries. The process is mentioned on the [official site here](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html).

Answer (score 3):

use `pip install tkintertable` it also imports Tkinter

Comment: It didn't work. I am running on a company computer. I can't use binary packages to install tkinter. Is there a way to install from source or using pip?